# Subir archivos a un servidor remoto con java

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando una aplicación web en java que permita subir básicamente archivos(imagenes) a un servidor remoto.

Aqui esta el código:

```
public void fileUploadServer(){

    String URLPath = "http://someserver/api/upload_files/UploadToServer.php";
    String FilePath = "/home/user/Downloads/image.jpg";
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    URLConnection urlc = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLPath);
        System.out.println("URI: "+URLPath);
        urlc = url.openConnection();
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);

        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath)));

        int i;
        while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bis != null)
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (bos != null)
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
        String str;
        System.out.println("Server response:");
        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        inStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println("From (ServerResponse): " + ioex);
    }

}
```

Adicionalmente existe un archivo php en el servidor remoto llamado UploadToServer.php. Este archivo(servicio) recibe y guarda la imagen que llega en la carpeta correspondiente.

Aquí esta el contenidop del archivo php:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],      $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

El resultado cuando se envía a correr la funcion es que recibe la repuesta desde el servidor remoto diciendo que no encuentra la imagen que "aparentemente" debió subir al servidor remoto.

```
URI: http://someserver/api/upload_files/UploadToServer.php
Server response:
fail
```

Alguien puede por favor corregir/revisar el código, en donde pueda estar fallando para que el archivo no suba al servidor remoto.

O si alguien sabe de algún ejemplo, URL el cual pueda facilitar la implementación de este "problema".

Gracias de antemano

Comment: [Aquí un ejemplo](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por si te sirve este ejemplo, yo suelo hace este tipo de conexiones de la siguiente manera:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri, String nombreArchivo) {

    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);  //Aquí tu URL

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", sourceFileUri);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + nombreArchivo + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();


            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(Principal3Activity.this, "Imagen subida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(Principal3Activity.this, "Error al cargar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(Principal3Activity.this, "Error al subir la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        return serverResponseCode;

    }
}
```

Y a esta función la llamo desde dentro de un hilo nuevo, de esta manera:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    uploadFile(imagepath, "nombreDelArchivo.jpg"); //Dos parámetros (ruta del archivo, nombre del archivo)

                }
            }).start();
```

Comprueba, eso sí, que estés poniendo bien la dirección URL del servidor y que esta carpeta tenga los permisos necesarios, es decir 0644

Suerte!

**EDITO:**
Aquí te añado cómo tengo desarrollado mi archivo .php

```
<?php

        $imagename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
          $source = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
          $target = $imagename;
          move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

          $imagepath = $imagename;
          $save = $imagepath;
          $file = $imagepath;

          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 


          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height) ; 
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
          imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height) ; 

          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 10) ; 

          $save = "smlx_" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
          $file =  $imagepath;

          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

          $modwidth = 150; 

          $diff = $width / $modwidth;

          $modheight = 150; 
          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
          imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 10) ; 

?>
```

Ten en cuenta que yo lo que hago es que redimensionar la imagen cuando la recibo (para que no ocupe tanto al mostrarlo en la APP) y así la grabo en el servidor. Para eso es el método imagejpeg(), que le bajo resolución a un 10% al archivo jpg.

Comment: Gracias por responder Mimmetico, he testeado tu código y funciona bien, sin embargo, aunque reciba como respuesta "Imagen subida..." el archivo(la imagen) no esta en el servidor, es decir de alguna manera no sube el archivo al servidor remoto. Tienes alguna idea de lo que pueda ser? Esto es lo que sale en el LOGCAT:     Nombre de la Imagen del Handy: IMG_20190426_102430.jpg,     D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default,     E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property.    Gracias de antemano alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Con el tema de los servidores me pierdo un poco, pero asegúrate de que la carpeta donde estás intentando añadir la imagen existe en tu servidor y que tenga los permisos (escritura, lectura y modificación) correctos. En mi caso es una carpeta /public_html/uploads y esta carpeta "uploads" tiene los permisos 0644. El archivo .php también lo tengo dentro de esa carpeta, de lo contrario no funcionará. Y la url que apunta a ese archivo php es algo así como... "https://TU_URL/uploads/TU_ARCHIVO.php"

Comment: Una cosa que olvidé, y que puede ser la causa de tu error: Este código tienes que ejecutarlo en un dispositivo real, y no en un emulador. Si lo ejecutas en un emulador de android, no funcionará. Tenlo en cuenta. Saludos.

Comment: He probado tus sugerencias, es decir, he testeado en un Smartphone con Android 8.1. Carpeta uploads con permisos 0644; archivo.php dentro de la carpeta uploads; el URL ...url/uploads/archivo.php, pero tal parece que algo estoy haciendo mal, que a pesar que recibo "Image subida", no sube el archivo :(.  Una ultima pregunta, como se debe tener el archivo.php(Contenido)....es igual al que lo describo arriba? gracias de antemano una sugerencia.

Comment: Claro, acabo de editar mi respuesta anterior con la configuración de archivo php. Ten en cuenta que yo le bajo calidad a la imagen (a un 10%) antes de subirla al servidor. Pero si tu quieres subirla original, deberías ignorar esa parte.